# Can I render JSON.parse data to EJS?

Tags: json, node.js, express, ejs

I am new to NodeJS and Express (to coding, in general). I am trying to render data to an EJS view page so I can manipulate it in the front end. It looks something like this:

```
app.set('view engine','ejs');
var str = JSON.parse('[{"name":"bill", "age":"26"}, {"name":"jeff", "age":"32"}]');

str.forEach(function(data){
    console.log(data.name);
});

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
    res.render('data', {str:str});
});
```

I try to test it in the EJS file by typing in `<%= data %>` the output I am getting in the browser is [object Object],[object Object]. I feel like I am missing a few piece. Can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Edit: 
Thanks Booligoosh. Just want to add that I had to convert it back to JSON in the EJS side afterward to make it work. :)

Answer (score 8):

You are attempting to **print** an array containing two objects to the ejs template. In a template you only print **strings**.

To print an object to the template we first need to **stringify** it:

```
<%= JSON.stringify(str) %>
```

To access a property of the object in your array we reference the array **index** and the property **key**:

```
<%= str[0].name %>
```

To **iterate** over the array and print out all the values we use a **forEach**:

```
<ul>
    <% str.forEach(function(o) { %>
        <li><%= o.name %> - <%= o.age %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can you iterative over a string? If str is a string, I'm not sure how you're able to call forEach on it.

Answer (score 2):

In `ejs` template we can render json object as below:

```
<%- JSON.stringify(user) %>
```

I tried with `<%= JSON.stringify(user) %>` (**`<%=`**) but it will print asci code values for double-quotes.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
app.set('view engine','ejs');
var str = JSON.parse('[{"name":"bill", "age":"26"}, {"name":"jeff", "age":"32"}]');

str.forEach(function(data){
    console.log(data.name);
});

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
    res.render('data', {str: JSON.stringify(str) });
});
```

You will need to convert your JSON object back to a string before passing it to the template using `JSON.stringify`, otherwise it will just be rendered with `.toString`, which returns `[object Object],[object Object]`.